# "hello" path not found with the react-router-dom v6 and @types/react-router-dom v5.3.3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Main file:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, RouteProps, Routes, useLocation, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

export type PrivateRouteProps = RouteProps & {
  Element?: React.ComponentType<any>;
};

/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
function PrivateRoute({ children, path, Element, ...routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent }: any) {
  const { authorize, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath } =
    useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  const match = useMatch(path?.toString() || '*');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated && !authenticating && match && location.pathname !== callbackPath) {
      const authorizeAsync = async () => {
        authorize(location as unknown as URL);
      };
      authorizeAsync();
    }
  }, [authorize, match, location, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath]);

  if (!authenticated) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        {...routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent}
        element={Element ? <Element /> : children}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Test file:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { PrivateRoute } from '..';
import AuthenticationContext, { AuthenticationContextProps } from '../AuthenticationContext';

describe('PrivateRoute', () => {
  function renderWithRouterAndContext(
    content: JSX.Element,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    { location, context } = {} as { location: string; context: object },
  ) {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [location] });
    const defaultContext: AuthenticationContextProps = {
      fetchToken: () => 'xyz' as any,
      callbackPath: '/oauth',
      setError: () => {},
      authenticated: false,
      authenticating: false,
      authorize: () => {},
      logout: () => {},
      getToken: () => 'xyz',
    };
    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{ ...defaultContext, ...context }}>
        <Router history={history as any}>{children}</Router>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );
    return {
      ...render(content, { wrapper } as any),
      history,
    };
  }

  describe('when authenticated', () => {
    it('can render children', () => {
      const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
        <PrivateRoute path="/hello">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </PrivateRoute>,
        { location: '/hello', context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true } },
      );
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hello</h1>');
    });

    it('can render a component', () => {
      function MyComponent() {
        return <h1>Hey</h1>;
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
      const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(<PrivateRoute component={MyComponent} />, {
        location: '/hello',
        context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true },
      });
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hey</h1>');
    });

    it('can invoke a render prop function', () => {
      const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
        <PrivateRoute
          render={({ history, location }: any) => <p>{${history.length} ${location.pathname}}</p>}
        />,
        { location: '/hello', context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true } },
      );
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<p>1 /hello</p>');
    });
  });

  describe('when unauthenticated', () => {
    const authorize = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('for a matching path', () => {
      it('checks user authorization and does not render anything', () => {
        const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <PrivateRoute path="/hello">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </PrivateRoute>,
          {
            location: '/hello',
            context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize },
          },
        );
        expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('');
        expect(authorize).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ pathname: '/hello' }));
      });
    });

    describe('for an OAuth callback path', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization and does not render anything', () => {
        const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <PrivateRoute path="/">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </PrivateRoute>,
          {
            location: '/oauth?code=xyz&state=foo',
            context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize },
          },
        );
        expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('');
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });

    describe('for a non-matching path', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization', () => {
        renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <PrivateRoute path="/hello">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </PrivateRoute>,
          { location: '/hi', context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize } },
        );
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });

    describe('when authentication is in progress', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization', () => {
        renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <PrivateRoute path="/hello">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </PrivateRoute>,
          {
            location: '/hi',
            context: {
              callbackPath: '/hello',
              authenticating: true,
              authorize,
            },
          },
        );
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

With the new version of react-router-dom v6 and @types/react-router-dom v5.3.3, after resolving some errors with the code changes it was giving the "hello" path not found error.

Error:

console.warn
No routes matched location "/hello"

```
  31 |     );
  32 |     return {
> 33 |       ...render(content, { wrapper } as any),
     |                ^
  34 |       history,
  35 |     };
  36 |   }
```

● PrivateRoute › when authenticated › can render children

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "<h1>Hello</h1>"
Received: ""

  44 |         { location: '/hello', context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true } },
  45 |       );
> 46 |       expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hello</h1>');
     |                                   ^
  47 |     });
  48 |
  49 |     it('can render a component', () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (packages/auth/src/_tests_/PrivateRoute.test.tsx:46:35)
```

● PrivateRoute › when authenticated › can render a component

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "<h1>Hey</h1>"
Received: ""

  56 |         context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true },
  57 |       });
> 58 |       expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hey</h1>');
     |                                   ^
  59 |     });
  60 |
  61 |     it('can invoke a render prop function', () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (packages/auth/src/_tests_/PrivateRoute.test.tsx:58:35)
```

● PrivateRoute › when authenticated › can invoke a render prop function

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "<p>1 /hello</p>"
Received: ""

  66 |         { location: '/hello', context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true } },
  67 |       );
> 68 |       expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<p>1 /hello</p>');
     |                                   ^
  69 |     });
  70 |   });
  71 |
```

Appriciate some suggessions, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Route` being rendered with a `"/hello"` `path` prop. The `PrivateRoute` component doesn't pass the `path` prop through to the `Route` it is rendering. You are overcomplicating the `PrivateRoute` component though. It should simply render an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their `element` content, or in the case of unauthenticated users, generally redirect them to a safe unprotected route.

Keeping your logic of rendering `null` for unauthenticated users though:

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const {
    authorize,
    authenticated,
    authenticating,
    callbackPath
  } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated
      && !authenticating
      && location.pathname !== callbackPath
    ) {
      const authorizeAsync = async () => {
        authorize(location as unknown as URL);
      };
      authorizeAsync();
    }
  }, [authorize, location, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath]);

  return authenticated ? <Outlet /> : null;
}
```

The unit tests should be refactored to render `PrivateRoute` as a layout route component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PrivateRoute } from '..';
import AuthenticationContext, {
  AuthenticationContextProps
} from '../AuthenticationContext';

describe('PrivateRoute', () => {
  function renderWithRouterAndContext(
    content: JSX.Element,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    { location, context } = {} as { location: string; context: object },
  ) {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [location] });

    const defaultContext: AuthenticationContextProps = {
      fetchToken: () => 'xyz' as any,
      callbackPath: '/oauth',
      setError: () => {},
      authenticated: false,
      authenticating: false,
      authorize: () => {},
      logout: () => {},
      getToken: () => 'xyz',
    };

    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{ ...defaultContext, ...context }}>
        <Router history={history as any}>{children}</Router>
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );

    return {
      ...render(content, { wrapper } as any),
      history,
    };
  }

  describe('when authenticated', () => {
    it('can render children', () => {
      const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>,
        {
          location: '/hello',
          context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true }
        },
      );
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hello</h1>');
    });

    it('can render a component', () => {
      function MyComponent() {
        return <h1>Hey</h1>;
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
      const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/hello" element={<MyComponent />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>,
        {
          location: '/hello',
          context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true },
        }
      );
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hey</h1>');
    });
  });

  describe('when unauthenticated', () => {
    const authorize = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('for a matching path', () => {
      it('checks user authorization and does not render anything', () => {
        const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>,
          {
            location: '/hello',
            context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize },
          },
        );
        expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('');
        expect(authorize).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          expect.objectContaining({ pathname: '/hello' })
        );
      });
    });

    describe('for an OAuth callback path', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization and does not render anything', () => {
        const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/oauth" element={<h1>OAuth</h1>} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>,
          {
            location: '/oauth?code=xyz&state=foo',
            context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize },
          },
        );
        expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>OAuth</h1>');
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });

    describe('for a non-matching path', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization', () => {
        renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/hi" element={<h1>Hi</h1>} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>,
          {
            location: '/hi',
            context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: false, authorize }
          },
        );
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });

    describe('when authentication is in progress', () => {
      it('does not check user authorization', () => {
        renderWithRouterAndContext(
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/hi" element={<h1>Hi</h1>} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>,
          {
            location: '/hi',
            context: {
              callbackPath: '/hello',
              authenticating: true,
              authorize,
            },
          },
        );
        expect(authorize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: With the above codec changes I added code changes to main file, After that getting /oauth path not found:
 No routes matched location "/oauth?code=xyz&state=foo" 
      33 |     return {
    > 34 |       ...render(content, { wrapper } as any),
         |                ^
      35 |       history,
      36 |     };
      37 |   }

Changed main file code with Outlet and Added test file which was in the above solutions that was provided by you.

Comment: in the main file code 

Added the code provided by you but changed the line 
`const PrivateRoute = () => {`

with `Function PrivateRoute () { ` .

Requesting clear code on the main code file

Comment: @ChinnaP You need to render a route on `path="/oauth"` for wherever you are trying to access it. I've updated the `'does not check user authorization and does not render anything'` test case which is the one I think you are referring to.

Comment: Requesting some help here, removed the below code from the test file, But the the removal of API may break the flow.

 `const { container } = renderWithRouterAndContext(<PrivateRoute component={MyComponent} />, {
        location: '/hello',
        context: { callbackPath: '/oauth', authenticated: true },
      });
      expect(container.innerHTML).toBe('<h1>Hey</h1>');
    });

    it('can invoke a render prop function', () => {`

Can you suggest something here without removing this API?

Comment: @ChinnaP Sorry, I don't quite follow what you are asking in that last comment.

Comment: in the above test case solution which was provided by you, it don't have the peace of code which I provided in the previous component regarding the render prop function(removed by you in the solution).
Can we add that in the test file without removing that API peace of code?

Comment: And everywhere in the test cases we have used <Routes> and <Route> Can't we keep the original code <PrivateRoute> there instead of <Routes> and <Route>

`<Routes>
            <Route path="/hi" element={<h1>Hi</h1>} />
            <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
              <Route path="/hello" element={<h1>Hello</h1>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>,`

Comment: @ChinnaP I see. I believe I removed those because the version of React-Router you are using doesn't supply the `Route` component APIs to "render with props". Also because of the API changes, `PrivateRoute` is no longer a "Route" component, it's a component rendered by a `Route` that allows access to nested routes it protects via the `Outlet`. RRDv6 uses *radically* different APIs and patterns than v5, so a lot of things in your code are very likely broken and will necessarily be different because of this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Chnaged my Main file PrivateRoute.tsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet, RouteProps, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

export type PrivateRouteProps = RouteProps & {
  Element?: React.ComponentType<any>;
};

/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
function PrivateRoute() {
  const { authorize, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath } =
    useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated && !authenticating && location.pathname !== callbackPath) {
      const authorizeAsync = async () => {
        authorize(location as unknown as URL);
      };
      authorizeAsync();
    }
  }, [authorize, location, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath]);

  return authenticated ? <Outlet /> : null;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Keep test cases same as you provided in the above solutions
Getting No match path /oauth error

console.warn
No routes matched location "/oauth?code=xyz&state=foo"

```
  32 |
  33 |     return {
> 34 |       ...render(content, { wrapper } as any),
     |                ^
  35 |       history,
  36 |     };
  37 |   }
```

Requesting some clear solutions here